# Show UIImagePickerController not modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to add a `UIImagePickerController` as the subview of a `UIView`, instead of presenting it modally?

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate=self;
[picker setSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Comment: The `UIImagePickerController` is only meant to presented modally on a iPhone or in a [`UIPopoverController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) on a iPad. For what you want you will have to build your own image picker with the use [Assets framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html)

Comment: @rckoenes is there a way to present a viewcontroller modally within a scrollview and still be able to scroll to other views?

Comment: View controllers are intended to control the action of the entire screen, not to be added as subviews (such as adding a controller to a `UIScrollView`)

Comment: Since you have to show is modally you can't place it in a scrollview. You will have to build your own with Assets Framework.

Comment: @rckoenes OK, is there a tutorial or resource showing how to build your own image picker? Thanks

Comment: Yes, many, do some googling around.  Ray Wanderlich is usually pretty thorough if you can find his.

Comment: Ask for offsite resource is offtopic for stackoverflow and I've already linked to the Apple Documentation for the Assets Framework.